# How can i access or execute .java file in another javafile in android app development?

Tags: android

i got 2 java files  app.java and gallaery.java

**App.java** 
public class App extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Button Listvideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Listvideo);
    Listvideo.setOnClickListener(this);
```

public void onClick(View view) {

if (view == findViewById(R.id.Listvideo)) {

```
   // i have to call gallery.java here which executes list of images in the android pone 

  }
```

}

Comment: Duplicate of the question you asked 30 min ago? [how do i call a java file on click in another java class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865238/how-do-i-call-a-java-file-on-click-in-another-java-class)

Comment: remormatted the question to understand it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Gallery.java also extends Activity you should call:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Gallery.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```