# How to start new activity on button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-button, android-lifecycle

In an Android application, how do you start a new activity (GUI) when a button in another activity is clicked, and how do you pass data between these two activities?

Comment: You can also follow the ans that helps me [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70620394/how-can-i-change-my-android-activity-on-button-click-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1279, accepted):

Easy.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Extras are retrieved on the other side via:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String value = intent.getStringExtra("key"); //if it's a string you stored.
}
```

Don't forget to add your new activity in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="NextActivity"/>
```

Comment: Where is the button click part? (button click → transition to next activity)

Comment: @Jonny: Here's an example of a button click. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7722428/442512

Comment: Is there any difference between `CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent)` and `startActivity(myIntent)`?

Comment: Yeah, easy lol. There is more codemissing than code actually typed. Where is all xml interface and .java code missing?
Downvote

Comment: Liquid, would you like him to pack it into an apk, too? ;)

Comment: It is also good to mention that you can also use CurrentActivity.this.finish(); at the end. Sometimes you don't want the user to end up on some error related activity when you redirected him and he presses the back button. What Finish() method does is that it destroys the current activity.

Comment: Casey fails to take into account that this is a beginner question. And so do those that upvoted it.
Because even the code included is wrong.

Answer (score 92):

Current responses are great but a more comprehensive answer is needed for beginners. There are 3 different ways to start a new activity in Android, and they all use the `Intent` class; [Intent | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

1. Using the `onClick` attribute of the Button. (Beginner)
2. Assigning an `OnClickListener()` via an anonymous class. (Intermediate)
3. Activity wide interface method using the `switch` statement. (not-"Pro")

Here's the [link](https://github.com/martinsing/ToNewActivityButtons) to my example if you want to follow along:

1. Using the `onClick` attribute of the Button. (Beginner)

---

Buttons have an `onClick` attribute that is found within the .xml file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="goToAnActivity"
    android:text="to an activity" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="goToAnotherActivity"
    android:text="to another activity" />
```

In Java class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
}

public void goToAnActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void goToAnotherActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Advantage**: Easy to make on the fly, modular, and can easily set multiple `onClick`s to the same intent.

**Disadvantage**: Difficult readability when reviewing.

2. Assigning an `OnClickListener()` via an anonymous class. (Intermediate)

---

This is when you set a separate `setOnClickListener()` to each `button` and override each `onClick()` with its own intent.

In Java class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AnActivity.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);}
            });

        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);}
            });
```

**Advantage**: Easy to make on the fly.

**Disadvantage**: There will be a lot of anonymous classes which will make readability difficult when reviewing.

3. Activity wide interface method using the `switch` statement. (not-"Pro")

---

This is when you use a `switch` statement for your buttons within the `onClick()` method to manage all the Activity's buttons.

In Java class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, AnActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

**Advantage**: Easy button management because all button intents are registered in a single `onClick()` method

---

For the second part of the question, passing data, please see [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Edit: not-"Pro"

Comment: Excellent Answer, thankyou! do you know about any performance penalty by using any of the suggestions ?

Comment: #3 is not "pro." It's the least readable and maintainable option, and it will be refactored into #1 or #2 by the first experienced developer who sees it. (Or they'll use Butterknife, which is option #1 on steroids.)

Comment: I think pro programmers doesn't like #3 at all. putting, Idk, 10 buttons click handler inside 1 method is a nightmare and is not professional at all. method with zilion lines of code doesn't make you professional. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: 3 is definitely not "pro"

Comment: Alright alright alright, it's not the "pro" answer, but I didn't get any other suggestions other than "not Pro". Fine, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 64):

Create an intent to a ViewPerson activity and pass the PersonID (for a database lookup, for example).

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ViewPerson.class);                      
i.putExtra("PersonID", personID);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in ViewPerson Activity, you can get the bundle of extra data, make sure it isn't null (in case if you sometimes don't pass data), then get the data.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null)
{
     personID = extras.getString("PersonID");
}
```

Now if you need to share data between two Activities, you can also have a Global Singleton.

```
public class YourApplication extends Application 
{     
     public SomeDataClass data = new SomeDataClass();
}
```

Then call it in any activity by:

```
YourApplication appState = ((YourApplication)this.getApplication());
appState.data.CallSomeFunctionHere(); // Do whatever you need to with data here.  Could be setter/getter or some other type of logic
```

Answer (score 37):

When user clicks on the button, directly inside the XML like that:

```
<Button
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="TextButton"
         android:onClick="buttonClickFunction"/>
```

Using the attribute **`android:onClick`** we declare the method name that has to be present on the parent activity. So I have to create this method inside our activity like that:

```
public void buttonClickFunction(View v)
{
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Your_Next_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

```
Intent iinent= new Intent(Homeactivity.this,secondactivity.class);
startActivity(iinent);
```

Comment: this is a partial answer only. moreover it's not sufficient, i.e. it won't work without additional modifications in the project.

Answer (score 11):

```
    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondaryScreen.class);    
    startActivity(in);

    This is an explicit intent to start secondscreen activity.
```

Answer (score 9):

## Kotlin

**First Activity**

```
startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
  .putExtra("key", "value"))
```

**Second Activity**

```
val value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key")
```

**Suggestion**

Always put keys in constant file for more managed way.

```
companion object {
    val PUT_EXTRA_USER = "user"
}
startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
  .putExtra(PUT_EXTRA_USER, "value"))
```

Answer (score 8):

Emmanuel,

I think the extra info should be put before starting the activity otherwise the data won't be available yet if you're accessing it in the onCreate method of NextActivity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

myIntent.putExtra("key", value);

CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this simple method.

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 7):

From the sending Activity try the following code

```
   //EXTRA_MESSAGE is our key and it's value is 'packagename.MESSAGE'
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "packageName.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ....

        //Here we declare our send button
        Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //declare our intent object which takes two parameters, the context and the new activity name

                // the name of the receiving activity is declared in the Intent Constructor
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NameOfReceivingActivity.class);

                String sendMessage = "hello world"
                //put the text inside the intent and send it to another Activity
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, sendMessage);
                //start the activity
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```

From the receiving Activity try the following code:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //use the getIntent()method to receive the data from another activity
 Intent intent = getIntent();

//extract the string, with the getStringExtra method
String message = intent.getStringExtra(NewActivityName.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Then just add the following code to the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
  android:name="packagename.NameOfTheReceivingActivity"
  android:label="Title of the Activity"
  android:parentActivityName="packagename.NameOfSendingActivity"
```

Answer (score 7):

```java
Intent i = new Intent(firstactivity.this, secondactivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting an activity from another activity is very common scenario among android applications.
To start an activity you need an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) object.

### How to create Intent Objects?

An intent object takes **two** parameter in its constructor

1. **Context**
2. **Name of the activity** to be started. (or full package name)

> #### Example:

[image]

So for example,if you have two activities, say `HomeActivity` and `DetailActivity` and you want to start `DetailActivity` from `HomeActivity`    **(HomeActivity-->DetailActivity).**

Here is the code snippet which shows how to start DetailActivity from

> HomeActivity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,DetailActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

And you are done.

> Coming back to button click part.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someid);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,DetailActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);  
      }

});
```

Answer (score 5):

The way to start new activities is to broadcast an intent, and there is a specific kind of intent that you can use to pass data from one activity to another. My recommendation is that you check out the Android developer docs related to [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html); it's a wealth of info on the subject, and has examples too.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
FirstActivity.this.SecondActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 4):

## Kotlin 2022

The simplest way:

```kotlin
val a = Intent(this.context, BarcodeActivity::class.java)
        a.putExtra("barcode", barcode)
        startActivity(a)
```

and in the other side (BarcodeActivity in my case):

```kotlin
val intent: Intent = intent
var data = intent.getStringExtra("barcode")
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132729/get-string-extra-from-activity-kotlin)

Answer (score 3):

Start another activity from this activity and u can pass parameters via Bundle Object also.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("USER_NAME", "xyz@gmail.com");
startActivity(intent);
```

Retrive data in another activity (YourActivity)

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_NAME");
```

Answer (score 3):

// In **Kotlin** , you can do as
/* In First Activity, let in activity layout there is button which has id as button.
Suppose I have to  pass data as String type from one activity to another  */

```
     val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
     btn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(baseContext, SecondActivity::class.java).apply {
             putExtra("KEY", data)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
     }
```

// In Second Activity, you can get data from another activity as

```
 val name = intent.getStringExtra("KEY")
```

/*  Suppose you have to pass a Custom Object then it should be Parcelable.
let there is class Collage type which I have to pass from one activity to another
*/

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class Collage(val name: String, val mobile: String, val email: String) : Parcelable
```

/* Activity First  , let here data is Collage type. which I have to pass to another activity. */

```
val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
         btn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(baseContext, SecondActivity::class.java).apply {
                 putExtra("KEY", data)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
         }
```

// then from second Activity we will get as

```
val item = intent.extras?.getParcelable<Collage>("KEY")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Implement the View.OnClickListener interface and override the onClick method.

```
ImageView btnSearch;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search1);
        ImageView btnSearch = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSearch: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Search.this,SearchFeedActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although proper answers have been already provided but I am here for searching the answer in language Kotlin. This Question is not about language specific so I am adding the code to accomplish this task in Kotlin language.

Here is how you do this in Kotlin for andorid

```
testActivityBtn1.setOnClickListener{
      val intent = Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java)
      startActivity(intent)

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Most simple way to open activity on button click is:

1. Create two activities under the res folder, add a button to the first activity and give a name to `onclick` function.
2. There should be two java files for each activity.
3. Below is the code:

MainActivity.java

```java
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void goToAnotherActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```java
package com.example.myapplication;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml(Just add this block of code to the existing)

```xml
 </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take Button in xml first.

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/pre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:text="Your Text"
        />
```

Make listner of button.

```
 pre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**When button is clicked:**

```
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("data", value); //pass data
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**To received the extra data from `NextActivity.class` :**

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extra != null){
    String str = (String) extra.get("data"); // get a object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the code in your first activity .

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondAcitvity.class);
                       //You can use String ,arraylist ,integer ,float and all data type.
                       intent.putExtra("Key","value");
                       startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
            }
         });
```

In secondActivity.class

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Key");
```

Answer (score 1):

Place button widget in xml like below

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
/>
```

After that initialise and handle on click listener in Activity like below ..

In Activity On Create method :

```
Button button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button); 
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       Intent intent = new 
            Intent(CurrentActivity.this,DesiredActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An old question but if the goal is to switch displayed pages, I just have one activity and call setContentView() when I want to switch pages (usually in response to user clicking on a button).  This allows me to simply call from one page's contents to another.  No Intent insanity of extras parcels bundles and whatever trying to pass data back and forth.

I make a bunch of pages in res/layout as usual but don't make an activity for each.  Just use setContentView() to switch them as needed.

So my one-and-only onCreate() has:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

    final View mainPage = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    setContentView (mainPage);
    Button openMenuButton = findViewById(R.id.openMenuButton);

    final View menuPage = layoutInflatter.inflate(R.layout.menu_page, null);
    Button someMenuButton = menuPage.findViewById(R.id.someMenuButton);

    openMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(menuPage);
        }
    });

    someMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            do-something-interesting;
            setContentView(mainPage);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the Back button to go back through your internal pages before exiting the app, just wrap setContentView() to save pages in a little Stack of pages, and pop those pages in onBackPressed() handler.

Comment: I really like this solution. I don't know if there are any downsides, but this approach seems super easy, and everything stays in the same instance, so managing state is easier.

Answer (score 1):

your button xml:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="jump to activity b"
    />
```

Mainactivity.java:

```
 Button btn=findViewVyId(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(btnclick);
btnclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setClass(Mainactivity.this,b.class);
                startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 imageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
// your code here
        });
```