# Button Click event not performed

Tags: android

I have write the following code in the onCreate() method of Activity class

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
                params.screenBrightness = 0;
                getWindow().setAttributes(params);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        btn.performClick();
```

But the problem is that the action on the button click is not happened, but if I click on that button then this action is performed.

I want to lock the screen by using that code, but it locks after the full execution of onCreate() method,

Any guess how i can do this.

Comment: What is working and what does not?

Comment: It was working only when i click that button

Comment: it is working without clicking the button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
final Button backto_main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back3x3); 
    backto_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {                 
            //add your code here..
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
            params.screenBrightness = 0;
            getWindow().setAttributes(params);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: button click work on when i click, but by btn.performClick() no effects is happen

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is

Make a `function` by moving the following codes :

```
 private void doSth(){
     WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
     params.screenBrightness = 0;
     getWindow().setAttributes(params);
     Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And instead of doing   `btn.performClick();` call the function `doSth()` in `onCreate()` .

and modify your `onClickListener` as :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                doSth();
            }
        });
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: no, it definitely works; and the problem is your coding implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
btn.performClick();
```

Comment: by removing this, nothing happens

Comment: then @gt_ebuddy satisfies your question, unless you implement totally wrong.