# I want my button, when pressed, it will be able to switch to another layout

Tags: android, button

How can I launch another layout when button is pressed? 
I followed some of the web's solution, but it doesn't seem to help me out.

Comment: This was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-a-new-activity-when-click-on-button

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you simply want to change the view for the entire Activity, you can do `setContentView(R.layout.newLayout)` but that is a really bad way to do it.

What you should do instead is `startActivity(new Intent(context, NewActivity.class));`

You would do that like this:

```
Button button = (Button)context.findViewById(R.id.button);

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       //Put the necessary methods here.
     }
}
```

Though in the future, you really should try to do more research before asking a question like this. I had the same question when I was new to Android, but Google and StackOverflow were able to resolve it by searching for the answer. The [Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html) also helps if you peruse it enough.

Comment: thankyou so much for this info, was searching for it but unable to get the right tags.

Comment: right now, using the way you gave, i am facing one error. 
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Context

Comment: replace `context` with `this` or just call findViewById() without it as it should already be in scope