# How to Program another page on buttons in eclipse?

Tags: android

I have programmed a few buttons on my main.xml and in my java.
But what I want to know is that lets say I tap the button it brings me to another page of buttons.
How do I program those buttons?
I tried creating another java but that will not work.

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=on+button+click+start+activity+in+android&pbx=1&oq=on+button+click+start+activity+in+android&aq=0j&aqi=g-j1&aql=&gs_sm=1&gs_upl=55918l55918l1l57024l1l1l0l0l0l0l117l117l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5caab28acf873349&biw=1280&bih=923

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-a-new-activity-when-click-on-button

Answer (score 2):

In **myMenu.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button bButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startActivity(new Intent("com.jom.tutbasics.TUTORIALONE"));
        }
    });
```

In **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity android:name=".tutorialOne"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.jom.tutbasics.TUTORIALONE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In **tutorialOne.java**

```
 public class tutorialOne extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial1);
            ...
```

and **tutorial1.xml** whatever you want to be in the opened page.

Comment: i know how to do this already!