# Create constructor in Android

Tags: android

I am new in Android platform.How to create different types of constructors (overloaded) of a particular Activity.. Is it similar to java or any difference is there? Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you would like to create different constructors for an activity. You should read about activity lifecycle ([example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)), and then how to create an activity from another activity ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-a-new-activity-when-click-on-button)).

This should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's just Java and you do in fact create classes derived from Activity. If you were able to [install](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) the tools, then you're resourceful enough to go through any one of these fine tutorials:

- http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html
- http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/android-tutorial/