# How to start a new activity when I click on button?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to start a new activity when click on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-a-new-activity-when-click-on-button)

I want to make my app go to a new screen when i click a button? Do i need a new activity for this or is there another way? If it is an activity can someone tell me how to make a button linked to a activity? thanks!

p.s. Please tell me which files the code u say go in, thansk!

***EDIT: I appologize for my lack of awareness of the sites policys on searching for things, I am new to this and apologize. Thanks for the help though for linking me to the right spot for this. Once again sorry guys.***

Comment: It sounds like you really need to start at the beginning. I recommend the series of tutorials by Vogella, http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html. stackoverflow tends to appreciate questions better when the poster shows that they've already made an effort to get started.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the xml-button definition

```
<Button
...
android:onClick="buttonClicked"
/>
```

in the activity

```
public void buttonClicked( View v ){
Intent i = new Intent( this, NewActivity.class );
startActivity( i );
}
```

Here you go

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already have a button defined.
All you need to do is:

```
//Here you define a lisener that will be fired every time you press on the button
Button btnOpenActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
btnOpenActivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Here you start the activity, by creating and passing an Intent
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent (YOUR CONTEXT, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity (activityIntent);
    }
});
```

That's it.

Because it looks like you are a beginner in Android programming, I would recommend you to go to `TheNewBoston` channel in youtube. This is where I learned android programming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a new `Activity`. Or you could use `Fragments`. `Activity` is probably the easiest method, and yes, it can be done with a button click:

```
    Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent newIntent = new Intent (this, ActivityYouWantToStart.class);
        startActivity (newIntent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to display a new screen - you'll need to create a new activity and its corresponding layout xml file.

Suppose you have two activities: `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity` and you want to open the later from the former. In that case you can set the event listener for the button on `FirstActivity` as:

```
btnSecondScreen.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    }
);
```