# Move from Activty 1 to Activity 2 keeping Activity 1 running

Tags: android, android-activity

How to move from Activity A to Activity B without disturbing Activity A. On button click, I want to move to Activity B from Activity A, but i still want Activity A to run.

I dont want to use Service as i m not understanding it. Please tell me of any other way to do this..

Comment: Define 'to run'. What do you want your ActivityA to keep doing and why

Comment: I am using GPS in activity A, so i want it to keep running even if i move to activity B. they belong to the same application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run a `Service` when `ActivityA` calls `onPause()` or `onStop()` then you can stop the `Service` in `onResume()` and resume your `Activity` from where the `Service` left off. See the **[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)**. You may not understand them but you need to take the time to read through about `Services` if you want it to function correctly. I believe there is even an example of this same thing in there. In `onPause()` you can call

[This part of the docs will be extremely helpful in understanding also](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 0):

When move from Activity A to Activity B. Activity A call onStop() method. So you can do what you want in the onStop().

```
    @Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
//Do something here
}
```

All about Activity, refer to : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: if i put my code in onStop(), it will run whenever i call any other activity. right?

Comment: This won't keep the code running while in the other `Activity` it will run whatever code is in `onStop()` before showing the next `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

The first activity will still exist when you start the second one. It won't be "running" but it'll call the `onPause()` method if Activity A is still visible underneath Activity B. If Activity A is no longer visible at all, it'll call the `onStop()` method.

You said you don't want to use a Service, but if you want to still have some part of Activity A running while a new activity is shown, I would consider using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or some kind of [Threading](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) that gets started in either the `onPause()` or the `onStop()` method of the activity.

Comment: so this means that if i call Activity B, Activity A will be paused?

Comment: Either paused or stopped, depending on if Activity A is still visible (Activity B might be a lightbox).