# How to start an Android Activity from an OSGI Bundle start method

Tags: android, android-activity, osgi, bundle, toast

I am trying to display a Toast message in an OSGI Bundle which obviously uses the Android API.  The toast needs an application context so I thought of creating an activity first inside my bundle. Here's my activity class with the toast message:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "This is OSGI Bundle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}
```

Now I would like to start the above activity from my start() method in the Bundle Activator class. below is that class:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    private static BundleContext context;

    static BundleContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }


    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = bundleContext;

   //I WOULD LIKE TO START THE ACTIVITY HERE TO DISPLAY THE TOAST MESSAGE



    }


    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = null;



    }

}
```

How can I achieve that? The only way I am aware of to start an activity is when you are in another activity like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click), which is not my case. Can someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think my topic will provide a response to you, even if not perfect. You may also check FelixDroid which is using a different approach seen on other projects. However, I long for a better solution. Going to see if I can find or write a ContextWrapper that will fill the bill.

[Full Android support for OSGi bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587855/full-android-support-for-osgi-bundles-knopflerfish)