# start osgi bundle in android application

Tags: android, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am embedding Apache Felix into an android application.
And then I install and start other four system bundle in android application.
These four system bundle are installed successfully.
But when I want to start them,it is wrong.
So I can't start these four system bundle.

```
The wrong message is following:
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]  
My code is very simple.
Could you help me solve this problem?Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CN7b.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8SAC.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFwWG.jpg
```

Comment: Did you researched here http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587855/full-android-support-for-osgi-bundles

Comment: Yes,What you provide I have finished.But now I want to start Felix and install other bundle in Android project using java code.The Felix is started successfully,but when I want to install and start my own bundle,it didn't successfully start.The wrong message is that "can't support this type of class file".I feel very confused.Can anyone help me>

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can help you further.