# Is Android SDK an OSGI Framework?

Tags: java, android, osgi

Been reading about OSGI a bit, and the structure of Android SDK made me wonder...

Is Android SDK made in OSGI?

Comment: You can check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587855/full-android-support-for-osgi-bundles

Answer (score 2):

No.  Not even remotely so. I'm not even sure why you'd think that.