# listView android, how to move to another activity

Tags: android, listview

I want to develop an android application using listView, what I want to do is when I press on an Item on the list it will take me to another activity and so on, how can I do that

Comment: What did you already try? Did you try google?

Comment: @L.Butz I tried google it, but all the examples I saw just display a toast not taking me to another activity

Comment: You could use this example instead of displaying a toast: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click

Comment: @L.Butz I know how to do that but I don't know how to do that using ListView

Answer (score 1):

> I want to develop an android application using listView

I guess you should try using Eclipse ADT to develop apps :D

What you are looking for is an `OnItemClickListener`. Usage:

```
 yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override 
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{ 
    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, yourNextActivity.class));
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many samples for this. To summarize it will be something like this:

yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(<YourCurrentActivity>.this, <YourNextActivityToStart>.class);
        startActivity(intent);
   }
```

});