# Intent to start an activity class from android application class

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a small libgdx game. I want to call an Activity class from AndroidApplication class. I used the following code

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(MyClass.this,NewActivity.class));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the problem then? what error you getting? post your logcat traces

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: The activity is not starting @Sukan

Comment: @Saqib The activity is not getting started

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: But why do you want to start a activity instead of game object from AndroidApliction

Comment: @NatwarSingh I need to create a SQLite database

Comment: can you plz add your code. how to trying to start activity.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Not able to create intents without context in andoid application class

Comment: try adding context.startActivity(i); , whats the value of your context? and are you extending Activity?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the code-

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyClass.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Or

```
Intent i= new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Or

```
startActivity(new Intent(MyClass.this, NewActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

`Intent i=new Intent(MyClass.this,NewActivity.class);
startActivity(i);`