# How to pass value from Button click event to another class in Android?

Tags: android, function, button

I am trying to write a code in Android to pass a value from a button click to another class. I am getting 0 value in the Log and i am not finding any technique to send the proper value.

Please go through my below code :

**Java Code:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mybuttonvalue;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

Activity activity;

Context cont;

public static int mysum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MySum.class);

            intent.putExtra("key",5);

            startActivityForResult(intent,2); 




        }
    });


}

@Override  
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
   {  
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  

              // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
               if(requestCode==2)  
                     {  





                     }  

 } }
```

**MySum.java**

```
 package com.example.mybuttonvalue;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;

 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MySum extends Activity
 {

    Activity activity;

    Context context;

    int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0); // 0 is default vlaue

    public MySum(Activity activity,Context cont)
    {

        this.activity = activity;

        this.context = cont;

    }

    public void check(final int x)
    {



        final Dialog dia = new Dialog(context);

        dia.requestWindowFeature(dia.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 

        dia.setContentView(R.layout.check);

        Button btn = (Button) dia.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                 int no = 12+x;

                 myvalue(no);

                 Intent intent= getIntent();  
                  intent.putExtra("result",x);  
                  setResult(2,intent);  

                 dia.dismiss();

            }
        });

        dia.show();



    }

    public String myvalue(int x)
    {

         return String.valueOf(x);

    }

}
```

**Log Report**

```
05-18 23:04:29.603: D/My Value :(10375): 0
```

This is the above code , how can i get 17 in the Log. I should get the result from MySum class to MainActivity class.

Please let me know , suggest me some good solution.

Comment: you declare a static variable in MainActivity.java..ie `public static mysum;` and refer this variable in `Mysum` like `MainActivity.mysum` and assign values to it..This value will be available in MainActivity also...

Comment: And, do you really need context AND activity in params ?

Comment: i think not really ...

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a Activity class `public class MySum extends Activity` which is wrong

```
MySum my = new MySum(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this);
```

Remove the constructor and the above code.

You need to use intent to pass values between activities. To get value back in `MainActivity` use `startActivityForResult` and override `onActivityResult` and get the value using intent.

Example:

In MainActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MySum.class);
intent.putExtra("key",5);
startActivityForResult(intent,2);
```

Then override `onActivityResult`

```
 @Override  
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
   {  
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  

              // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
               if(requestCode==2)  
                     {  
                       //get data using intent
                       int result = data.getIntextra("result",0);

                     }  

 }
```

In MySum.java

```
int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0); // 0 is default vlaue
```

Do operation on value

Then to return result

```
  Intent intent= getIntent();  
  intent.putExtra("result",x);  
  setResult(2,intent);
```

Edit:

```
public class MySum extends Activity
{

 @Override
 protectes void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mysumlayout); //set layout for mysum
    int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);
    check(value);

}
public void check(int x)
{

    final Dialog dia = new Dialog(MySum.this);
    dia.requestWindowFeature(dia.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    dia.setContentView(R.layout.check);
    Button btn = (Button) dia.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

             int no = 12+x;
             dia.dismiss();
             Intent intent= getIntent();  
             intent.putExtra("result",no);  
             setResult(2,intent);  
             finish(); 


        }
    });

    dia.show();
} 
}
```

Note:

Apart from the above code which is just an example you need not have a Activity at all. All you do is some calculation on a int value which does not require a ui. It could be a normal java class which does just some operation without dialog or any other ui stuff.

Comment: can it be considerate a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click?

Comment: @blackbelt could be. Vote to close. Anyway i will complete my answer by editing

Comment: Gettin No Scope error on this Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MySum.this); The constructor Intent(MainActivity, MySum) is undefined

Comment: @user2551103 typo error. sorry. its `MySum.class`. MySum must be declared in manifest file

Comment: NO friend code is not working ... getting NullPointerException on line 18 of MySum.java  ....

Comment: @user2551103 this will work provided you do it right. Something on line 18 is null. Post what you have done by editing your post. How do i know what is line 18?

Comment: @user2551103 you are supposed to ActivityCOntest here `final Dialog dia = new Dialog(MySum.this);`

Comment: @user2551103 you need to read the docs more.. check the edit

Comment: @user2551103 still having problem you will find a complete example @ http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: @user2551103 is it done? working??