# Android multiple-screen app network operation

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to Android development.

My application needs to work this way:

1. At startup it will login to TCP Server
2. Based upon login it will communicate as a `httpclient` through web services to a web server.

The above two tasks have been  successfully implemented in individual projects with the help of AsyncTask.
I want to implement both tasks in one project.

So in "Main activity" I have username/password fields then "Next" button to launch web services interface through an Intent. But it cannot launch the web service interface through the Intent.
How could I implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by `it cannot launch the web service interface`? Is it to call an web API?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. web services interface means it can't launch another activity where we can call web services.

Comment: I don't get from where you want to open another `Activity`? Is it an `Acitivty` or a `Fragment` from where you're creating `Intent`?

Comment: As mention above i want to launch new activity through intent from "Main activity".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: The `TCP Server` is not the same as the `web server` you mentioned? I understand that you know how to start a second activity in a button on click listener but that you want to pass some params. Maybe the ones that you call 'the web service interface` ? What exactly?