# I want to use Tab View without extending TabActivity . What is best way to use TabView?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Below is my requirement, I want to use Tabview like below and Each tab have some UI and Task to do. But when i switch Tab , background process should be active.

Like, initially one Tab is related to Main Thread, and others Tabs are static one.

[image]

What is the best way  to do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: these buttons UI are written in fragment xml, how u can inflate button from main.xml ? i know how to switch A to A.

Comment: you can't load Activity in TabView...

Comment: right , what is the solution?

Comment: You can load another fragment, for example.

Comment: u can use [`ActionBar` with tab navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)