# Only works in Main Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, program-entry-point

So I have a code, that's only works in the MainActivity, and I don't know how to make it work, in the second activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Resources res = getResources();

        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);

        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(q);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void ButtonOnClick (View v) {
        Button button = (Button) v;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_szabaly);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I start my app, in the first activity the text is changing(because it's a random text changing code), but when I press the button, that makes me go to the second activity, nothing happens, no action in the second activity.

What am I doing wrong?

My Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Szabaly"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_szabaly" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you add the android:onClick attribute in the layout ? this is bad practice

better implementing  View.OnClickListener

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String[] myString;
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Resources res = getResources();

    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);

    String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(q);
    //finde button
    Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    //set OnClickListener
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Szabaly.class);
            startActivity(intent );
            break;
       }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually starting a new activity on your button click. Instead you're just changing your view. This will not be cause to call the `onCreate` method again.

```
public void ButtonOnClick (View v) {
    Button button = (Button) v;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_szabaly);
}
```

This code is only changing the view. To start a new activity you'd need to create a new class that extends Activity (just like MainActivity) and register it in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Then you'll be able to start the new activity on click by the following

```
public void ButtonOnClick (View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click) question for more detail on starting a new Activity from a button click.