# Android start new activity when clicking widget

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am new with coding Java and xml for android applications and I wanted to know how I start/open a new activity when clicking on something. In this case I am using a relative layout to keep a image and text together as one object. What I want to do is when you click on it it will start/open the new activity. How do I do this? Could someone tell me step by step since I am quite new to this.

Comment: It's all here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent the official docs are usually a good place to start if you have tried nothing yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want your layout to act  (`RelativeLayout`) like a button (do not handle `onClick` on layout child components) firstly set in your xml layout file `RelativeLayout` attribute

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Or you can do this directly in your code (in `onCreate` method)

```
relativeLayout.setClickable(true);
```

Than you need to set `onClickListener` for your layout.
You can do this simply by creating anonymous class

```
relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
             {
              Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourDesiredActivity.class);
              startActivity(startActivityIntent);
             }
          }
```

**UPDATE**

Layout is defined in xml file, of course in Android you can do this in code ,but it is better to use xml file.

In your IDEA you have folder `res->layout` here you should place your layout files. For example  layout with name `

**`relative_root_layout.xml`**

```
    <xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/image_view">
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/icon"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ImageView>
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text_view"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view"
          android:text="Relative layout">
       TextView>
    RelativeLayout>
```

But in case you have only text and image it is better to use

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_image"
 android:text="Button with Image"
 android:gravity="left"
 android:drawablePadding="10dp">
Button>
```

How you can access your widgets ?
This is very basic thing you have to know if you are developing for android, this is essential part. Please read documentation, read books, watch tutorial or whatever.

In short you need to inflate layout in activity `onCreate()` method 
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.relative_root_layout);
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        mRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(.....)

}
```

But again this very basic things you must know.

Comment: This is great thank you so much, but how do I define which relative layout it should listen to? Where do I define the relative layout ID? And also, when I put it into my java code of my current activity, it is giving me the following errors:
"Cannot resolve symbol 'relative layout'"
"Cannot resolve symbol 'intent'"
"Cannot resolve symbol 'view'"
and then also the same for the activity I am trying to open. I apolagise for this I am quite new to all of this.

Comment: I have added the code into my Java file for my activity. On creation of a project I get a public class extend "ActionBarActivity". I am not really sure what I am supposed to start with this since it has a line through it. Do I need to change anything? I also noticed that I already have a void bundle saveinstance state. Everything is in the screenshot below.
This is what I have now: http://i.gyazo.com/49d7447e2e799cac7a928971e054c233.png
@CROSP

Comment: Upload your full code somewhere and give me a link. You don't have to override onCreate method twice . You have to declare mRelativeLayout as your class member.You haven't created relative_layout_file in your res folder this is about your screenshot .

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ygFDVZCE This is what I have by default with nothing changed. My main activity is called activity_selection_main and the one I want to go to is activity_selection_townhall. I want to have multiple relative layouts as buttons in a single activity leading to different other activities each.

Comment: Have a look http://pastebin.com/tLf9hkh8 this is your activity code. And this code for layout xml file activity_selection_main.xml in your case http://pastebin.com/QQRzH7B1. 
But if you want to have multiple items (clickable relative layouts) you must use ListView or RecyclerView with adapter. If my answer helpful please accept it.

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if it was possible for us to get in contact privately, via e-mail or Skype or something if that is okay with you. It would be great if you could help a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `onClickListener` for any of your views.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Youractivity.this, Moveactivity.class));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new activity is done by creating an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and then calling [`startActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29), e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AnotherActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

---

You can wrap this code in an [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) as other answerers already suggested.

A second option is to add an [`android:onClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick) attribute to your `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout ...
                android:onClick="clickMe">
    <ImageView .../>
    <TextView .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your activity

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void clickMe(View notused) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

See [startactivity](https://github.com/olafdietsche/android-samples/tree/master/startactivity) for a complete example.

Comment: Where do I put this code? Can you please help me with that. Sorry I am really bad at this and very new.