# How to fix an android 'IllegalStateException' error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am very new to android and just starting to understand how to develop simple apps (`AndroidStudio`, `Ubuntu 14.04`, LG G3). From a main activity I want to start another activity (i.e. to show a different screen where the user can make some input) following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click). In the file `MainActivity.java` I have the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_add:           
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewEntryActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            return true;          
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And the file `NewEntryActivity.java` is defined as follows:

```
package com.example.alexander.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewEntryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_newentry);

        final EditText editNewIsin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_isin);
        final EditText editNewPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_price);
        final EditText editNewNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_number);
        Button buttonNewOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_ok);
        Button buttonNewCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_cancel);


    }

}
```

No error is indicated for this file (everything seems to be defined properly). When I start the app on my phone, the main activity starts without problem, but when I choose the menu item to start the other activity the app closes immediately and I see an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

However, both activities are derived from `AppCompatActivity`. Maybe it refers to something else (Manifest, layout.xml, ...?), but this is not clear from the error message. Any help is appreciated here...

Here is also the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alexander.myapplication" >

    <application>
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/stoxx"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />     

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NewEntryActivity"
            android:label="@string/menu_add"
        />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is the theme for your activity in manifest?

Comment: I have no idea. Where can I see that? I probably don't have one defined...?

Comment: Manifest file for activity/application tag

Comment: I added the whole manifest file content to the question.

Comment: use @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar instead of @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar

Comment: This did not work, I get the same error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93512/discussion-between-alex-and-fahim).

Comment: Also, all of the other content xml files seem to miss a layout.

Comment: I wonder why I get downvoted. This is a valid programming question, without an obvious or trivial solution. I would like to understand why this question gets downvoted...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same theme as home in your other activity. like this

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/second"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: I have only 'style name="AppTheme"' in my `styles.xml` file. But when I replace this and the entry in the manifest file, I still get the same error as before.

Comment: Check the updated answer. this worked for me and kindly accept this answer if it works. Thanks

Comment: Do I need to put this 'AppTheme.NoActionBar' just to the new activity, or to the main application in the manifest as well? What about I have defined in styles.xml? And why do I need three places to define the theme? And why does the app crash because of a theme? Isn't that just how the graphics look? And what are the differences between those many themes? Where can I get answers to all of my questions?