# Call another Activity in Main Activity

Tags: java, android

sorry my question is may be very simple for all of you. But I am new and need solution for it. If you can help me for solve it.

I have one quote application which have function for check new quote from server in main activity, its checking with server on loading Main Activity that there new quotes available or not and if available its opening one popup window for go setting activity for download new quotes, and if user press setting button than its taking user to setting activity. I need some changes in it. I want automatic download new quotes from main activity without go setting activity. both activity are like below

Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    //String qotdId;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;
    public static boolean active;

    DAO db;

    String siteUrl, updatesUrl;
    int lastAuthor, lastQuote;

    private ConnectionDetector cd;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_publisher_interstitial_id));
        mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        super.onStart();
        active = true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        active = false;

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,           
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    /*  Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

        if (isFirstRun) {
            //show start activity

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Push Download Button And Save Status in Your Mobile For Just One Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }


           getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                    .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
                    */


    //  Parse push notification
        Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_application_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

        db = new DAO(this);
        db.open();

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(MainActivity.this);
        siteUrl = getResources().getString(R.string.siteUrl);
        updatesUrl = siteUrl + "site/get_updates/" + String.valueOf(lastAuthor) + "/" + String.valueOf(lastQuote);

        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present

            Intent checkUpdates = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CheckUpdatesService.class);

            startService(checkUpdates);
        }

    //  generateKeyHash();

        final ImageButton quotes = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.quotes);
        quotes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        QuotesActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("quotesType", 1);
                intent.putExtra("itemSelected", 0);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        final ImageButton authors = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.authors);
        authors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        AuthorsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        final ImageButton favorites = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favorites);
        favorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        QuotesActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("quotesType", 2);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        final ImageButton settings = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settings);
        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

And my other activity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;
    private static final String MY_PREFERENCES = "my_preferences";  


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_publisher_interstitial_id));
        mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        //unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onStop();

    }


    // ==========================================================================================================//

    DAO db;
    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen;

    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    UpdateClass update;

    // Internet Connection detector
    private ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    Preference more, rate, about, check, share,status,background, progress = null;
    PreferenceCategory socialsCategory;

    private MyDownloadReceiver receiver;
    // ==============================================================================

    ////////////////////     First Load   /////////////////

    public static boolean isFirst(Context context){
        final SharedPreferences reader = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        final boolean first = reader.getBoolean("is_first", true);
        if(first){
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = reader.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is_first", false);
            editor.commit();
        }
        return first;
    }       

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.config);
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        //TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = getResources().getString(
            //  R.string.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        //TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = getResources().getString(
        //      R.string.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        //TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://"
            //  + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            //  + ".SettingsActivity";

        //uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        //uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        db = new DAO(this);
        db.open();

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings);

        // Shared Preferences
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);           

        check = (Preference) findPreference("check");
        about = (Preference) findPreference("about");
        more = (Preference) findPreference("more");
        rate = (Preference) findPreference("rate");
        status = (Preference) findPreference("status");
        share = (Preference) findPreference("share");
        background = (Preference) findPreference("background");

        socialsCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("socials");

        preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();


        check.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                update = new UpdateClass(SettingsActivity.this);
                update.handleUpdates();
                //if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                //  mInterstitial.show();
                //}

                return false;
            }
        });

        // ==============================================================================

        about.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,
                        AboutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitial.show();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });


        // ==============================================================================

                background
                        .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                                    Object newValue) {

                                if (newValue.equals(true)) {
                                    db.updateSetting("background", "1");
                                } else {
                                    db.updateSetting("background", "0");
                                }

                                return true;
                            }
                        });

                // ==============================================================================

        // ==============================================================================

                rate.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                        final String appPackageName = "com.karopass.hindishayari2016";
                        try {startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+ appPackageName)));
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+ appPackageName)));

                        }
                        return true; 
                    }
                });

                // ==============================================================================

                more.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                        final String developerName = "karopass";
                        try {startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q="+ developerName)));
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/search?q="+ developerName)));

                        }
                        return true; 
                    }
                });


                share.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {    
                        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        String shareBody = "आज ही डाउनलोड करे हिंदी शायरी एप्लीकेशन और पाइए बेस्ट हिंदी शायरी.इस एप्लीकेशन में 3000 से भी ज्यादा बढ़िया हिंदी शायरी का कलेक्शन है जिसे आप पढने या शेर करने के लिए यूज कर सकते है !! आज ही डाउनलोड करे !! http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.karopass.hindishayari2016";
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " ");
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

                        return false;
                    }
                });


                // ==============================================================================

                status.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                        final String appPackageName = "com.karopass.hindi_status_2016";
                        try {startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+ appPackageName)));
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+ appPackageName)));

                        }
                        return true; 
                    }
                });

                // ==============================================================================


                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyDownloadReceiver.ACTION);
                filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                receiver = new MyDownloadReceiver();
                registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    }

    void showProgressBar() {
        progress = new MyProgressBarPreference(this);
        preferenceScreen.addPreference(progress);
    }

    void setDownloadProgress(int percent) {
        if (progress != null) {
            ((MyProgressBarPreference)progress).setProgress(percent);
            ((MyProgressBarPreference)progress).setLabel("Please wait... " +percent + "%"+" Downloading Done");
        }
    }

    void hideProgressBar()
    {
        if (progress != null)
            preferenceScreen.removePreference(progress);
    }

    public class MyDownloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public static final String ACTION = "com.karopass.hindishayari2016.intent.action.DOWNLOAD";

        public static final int INITIALIZE = 0x001;
        public static final int DOWNLOAD = 0x002;
        public static final int FINISH = 0x003;

        public static final String EXTRA_STATUS = "status";
        public static final String EXTRA_PERCENT = "percent";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int status = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

            Log.d("DESOLF", "receive broadcast : " + status);

            switch(status) {
            case INITIALIZE:
                showProgressBar();
                break;

            case DOWNLOAD:
                int percent = intent.getIntExtra(MyDownloadReceiver.EXTRA_PERCENT, 0);
                setDownloadProgress(percent);

                break;
            case FINISH:
                hideProgressBar();
                //Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Downloaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitial.show();
                }   
                break;


            default:

            }
        }
    }

    public class MyProgressBarPreference extends Preference {


        public MyProgressBarPreference(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
        public MyProgressBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public MyProgressBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        private ImageView mStatusIcon;
        private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
        private TextView mStatusText ;

        private int lastReqProgress=-1;
        private int lastReqMax=-1;
        private String lastLabel;

        @Override
        protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View myLayout=li.inflate(R.layout.download_progress, null, false);

            RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f);
            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            anim.setDuration(700);          
            mStatusIcon = (ImageView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.status_icon);
            mStatusIcon.startAnimation(anim);
            mProgressBar=(ProgressBar) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.status_progress);
            mStatusText=(TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.status_text);

            mStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.rotate);
            mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            mStatusText.setText(0 + "%");
            return myLayout;
        }


        public void setIcon(int resId) {
            mStatusIcon.setImageResource(resId);
        }

        public void setProgress(int value){
            if (mProgressBar!=null){
                mProgressBar.setProgress(value);
            } else {
                lastReqProgress=value;
            }

        }

        public void setMax(int value){
            if (mProgressBar!=null){
                int savedprogress=mProgressBar.getProgress();
                mProgressBar.setMax(0);
                mProgressBar.setMax(value);
                mProgressBar.setProgress(savedprogress);
            } else {
                lastReqMax=value;
            }

        }


        public void setLabel(String text){
            if (lastLabel!=null){
                mStatusText.setText(text);
            } else {
                lastLabel=text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Don't forget to add your Second Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="SecondActivity"/>
```

[Android Page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)