# View activities when a IF statement is true

Tags: android, android-studio

Need help with switching to an activity if my form details match the string. So when the login button is pressed it will display main activity. This is the code I have so far:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    setupVariables();
}

private void setupVariables() {
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

}

public void Login(View view) {
    if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("secret")) {
        /* switches activity if the username and password matches the string */
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: @joydroider Just did, error Lenght.Short) can't resolve symbol.

Comment: @DeeMoMo Sorry mistaken i have edited my answer. Please check edited part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Switching and working with activity.**

**You first might read details for this. Follow this.**

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

And try this with your code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    setupVariables();

}

private void setupVariables() {
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Login();
       }
    });

}

public void Login() {
    if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("secret")) {
        // Here you can switch your activity.
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondScreen.class);
        StartActivity(i);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid credentials.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And you not need to pass view parameter as you need to call it directly on `Button Click Listener` method.

**Edit**

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid credentials.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Hope this will help you to understand basics.**

Comment: @DeeMoMo Glad to Help :). Please upvote it also if u can Thanks :).

Comment: I did but got low rep!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the Login as the `onClick` function of the login button, you can use `Intent` like following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

you will it like this

```
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListener(){
     @override
     public void onClick(View v){
      Login();
    }
    });
public void Login() {
    if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("secret")) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {  
    Toast.makeText(this,"Cant't Login",Lenght.Short).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this onclick method

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin")&&password.getText().toString().equals("secret")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
               else {  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong username or password", 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
            }
        });
```

I am assuming that Login.java is your current class
EDIT--> try this

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    //On click function
    public void onClick(View view) {
if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin")&&password.getText().toString().equals("secret"))
{    
        //Create the intent to start another activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
else {
Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
}
});
```

Comment: I am receiving errors on can't resolve symbol for setOnClickListener, the v in (View v) and LENGTH_LONG @Praval Sharma

Comment: I edited my answer and paste another code for your errors @DeeMoMo

Comment: Again, now have an can't resolve symbol for 'button' at the beginning. The (new OnClickListener() has an error. And both (View view) and (view.getContext() have errors.

Comment: you have to use 'login' instead of 'button' because your 'login' is your button object and replace view.getcontext() with 'Login.this'. Here I am assuming Login is your current class.

Comment: Also i have changed code for your convenience @DeeMoMo

Answer (score 0):

For this please use "Intent" class, used to move from one activity to another activity or service.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(first_activity.class, Second_activity.class);
startactivity(intent);
```

or you can use

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getapplicationcontext(),Second_activity.class);
startactivity(intent)
```