# activity is not opening when button is clicked [ANDROID]

Tags: android

I am new to android and I want to call an activity named as *SetNotification* when SET NOTIFICATION button is clicked from the main activity, for that I have written this code but the activity is not opening when the button is clicked.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.abc.project1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static Button set_not;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClickButtonListener() {
        set_not = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set_not_btn);
        set_not.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.abc.project1.SetNotification");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abc.project1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SetNotification"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_set_notification"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.abc.project1.SetNotification" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_set_notification.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.abc.project1.SetNotification">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_set_notification" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Error**

```
04-30 16:12:03.681 9001-9001/com.example.abc.project1 I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-30 16:12:03.681 9001-9001/com.example.abc.project1 I/art: Late-enabling JIT
04-30 16:12:03.690 9001-9001/com.example.abc.project1 I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
04-30 16:12:03.891 9001-9001/com.example.abc.project1 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.abc.project1-2/lib/x86
04-30 16:12:04.232 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 36.566ms
04-30 16:12:04.650 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 48.347ms
04-30 16:12:04.836 9001-9028/com.example.abc.project1 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-30 16:12:05.234 9001-9028/com.example.abc.project1 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-30 16:12:05.475 9001-9028/com.example.abc.project1 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-30 16:12:05.475 9001-9028/com.example.abc.project1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xacaf6420, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-30 16:12:05.557 9001-9001/com.example.abc.project1 I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 16:12:06.275 9001-9001/com.example.abc.project1 I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 16:12:53.430 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.922ms
04-30 16:13:42.955 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.961ms
04-30 16:13:55.377 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 27.667ms
04-30 16:13:56.006 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 26.471ms
04-30 16:14:03.367 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 27.844ms
04-30 16:14:05.311 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.656ms
04-30 16:14:10.602 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.906ms
04-30 16:14:13.897 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.277ms
04-30 16:14:17.071 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.026ms
04-30 16:14:17.563 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.670ms
04-30 16:14:19.361 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.463ms
04-30 16:14:26.781 9001-9008/com.example.abc.project1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.556ms
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1):

Your intent should look like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetNotification.class);   
startActivity(intent);
```

By the way these aren't required:

```
public void onClickButtonListener() {  }
```

Just put your button and onclicklistener outside these lines of code and remove these lines of `onClickButtonListener`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent openActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetNotification.class);
startActivity(openActivity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide class not package name to `new Intent()` like

`Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SetNotification.class);
startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 1):

Your way of opening activity is wrong. Try it this way.

```
set_not.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SetNotification.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
```