# how to link a new activity in android studio using a clickable text

Tags: android

Please how do I link a new activity from my main activity using a clickable text. I have set the text to clickable from my main.xml but I don't know how to call the new activity from my MainActivity.java class. I know I have to use this code "textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());" I found in a similar question, but I don't know how and where to place it on my MainActivity.java class so that it calls a the next activity I named display

Comment: Could you please provide your code? For starting a new activity you have to create a new intent like this `Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class); startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). You use these to start new activities or services within your application.

You're correct in that you have to assign an `OnClickListener` interface to your text, after you made it clickable.  In the interface's `onClick()` method you would need to do something like this.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Create the intent which will start your new activity.
    Intent newActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);

    // Pass any info you need in the next activity in your
    // intent object.
    newActivityIntent.putExtra("aString", "some_string_value");
    newActivityIntent.putExtra("anInteger", some_integer_value);

    // Start the new activity.
    startActivity(newActivityIntent);
}
```

In the next activity, you can retrieve the intent used to start it, so that you'll have access to the data you passed from the first activity, like so:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the intent that started this activity.
    Intent startingIntent = getIntent();

    // Retrieve the values.
    String aString = startingIntent.getStringExtra("aString");
    Integer anInteger = startingIntent.getIntExtra("anInteger", 0); // 2nd param is the default value, should "anInteger" not exist in the bundle.

    // Use the values to your hearts content.
}
```

Hope that helps.