# How to seperate CMU pocketsphinx android demo into activities

Tags: android, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am currently working on CMU pocketpshinx for Android and wish to separate the menu window from the other windows into activities. I am fairly new to coding and am having difficulties with it. I think my code is right, I just don't know where to place it. Any help would be great !

Here is my new activity code (I am unsure where to place it in the PocketSphinxActivity Java file):

```
Intent i = new Intent("edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.BloodPressure");
startActivity(i)
Intent j = new Intent("edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.HeartRate");
startActivity(j)
Intent k = new Intent("edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PatientInfo");
startActivity(k)
```

Comment: Do add your code which you have already tried, it helps other understand and solve your problem better

Comment: I have edited my post to add the code. If you have the original Pocketsphinx android demo code, I have changed "Phones", "Forecast" etc into medical terms "BloodPressure", "HeartRate" etc

Comment: 1) You can only start one Activity. 2) Place this code inside some other Activity when you want to start these

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: I want to start three different activities from the one activity. Each activity is opened by a different voice command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the codes in `onPartialResult()` method. For different actions to be performed for different voice commands, you can use `if-else` or `switch` as per your need in the code.

I am assuming that your provided code for starting different new activities are ok and the `BloodPressure` class will run for listening the command "blood pressure", the `HeartRate` class will run for listening the command "heart rate" and the `PatientInfo` class will run for listening the command "patient info". I also assume that you have made correct configurations in your grammar files and recognition system to recognize the parts "blood pressure", "heart rate" and "patient info".

Then your code may go like this using `if-else`:

```
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis arg0) {
        if(arg0 == null){ return; }

        String command = arg0.getHypstr();

        if(command.equals("blood pressure")) {
            recognizer.stop();
            Intent i = new Intent("edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.BloodPressure");
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else if(command.equals("heart rate")) {
            recognizer.stop();
            Intent j = new Intent("edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.HeartRate");
            startActivity(j);
        }
        else if(command.equals("patient info")) {
            recognizer.stop();
            Intent k = new Intent("edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PatientInfo");
            startActivity(k);
        }
}
```

Hope this helps