# Expression Expected error

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

In Android Studio I want to a button to start a new Activity. I get an Expression Expected error. Where have I gone wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Button advanceToQuestionTwo = {Button};

  Button loadNewActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

  loadNewActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Stundenplan.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Line 6: wrapping a class in curly brackets does not an expression make.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: `advanceToQuestionTwo` is an incorrect variable assignment and not needed. Everything else looks okay. If you'd made a [mcve] you might have discovered that

Answer (score 2):

You must delete this line `Button advanceToQuestionTwo = {Button};` or complete it. You need to put `(Button)` and not `{Button}`. Then after that you should call `findViewById( id of that button in the xml file)`.