# Map Class's onCreate() and onMapReady() functions never ran

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I've created a basic Android app that is intended to have a map with a hamburger drawer on-top of that. Each hamburger menu option will run object methods on the GoogleMap object.

The issue is that while the hamburger drawer is created and works, the map's fragment is placed in the correct place, the onCreate and subsequently onMapReady functions in MainActivity are not running meaning the GoogleMap object is never made. I added some print statements to these functions to make sure and they are never printed.

I've got two classes, HamburgerDrawer.java and MainActivity.java.

HamburgerDrawer.java:

```
package com.vanleusen.brighthelp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton; 
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class HamburgerDrawer extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //testing

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hamburger_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    /*FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.frame_container, new MyFragment());
    transaction.commit();*/

    //MainActivity map = new MainActivity();

}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hamburger_drawer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_roadmap) {
        System.out.println("Roadmap");
        //mapData.mapTypeInterface(1);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_satellite) {
        System.out.println("Satellite");
        //mapData.mapTypeInterface(2);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_hybrid) {
        System.out.println("Hybrid");
        //mapData.mapTypeInterface(3);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_terrain) {
        System.out.println("Terrain");
        //mapData.mapTypeInterface(4);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_problems) {
        System.out.println("Report Problems");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
        System.out.println("Contact Us");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        System.out.println("About");
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.vanleusen.brighthelp;

/**
 * Created by Oscar on 22/10/2016.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public static MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_hamburger_drawer);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        System.out.println("Ran onCreate method");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        System.out.println("Ran onMapReady method");
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

I have multiple layout xml files to implement the hamburger menu, although the relevant one which contains the content for the drawer is here:

content_hamburger_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_hamburger_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.vanleusen.brighthelp.HamburgerDrawer"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_hamburger_drawer">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

        <view
            android:id="@+id/myview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            class="android.view.View" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally I've heard this may be connected to my AndroidManifest although I tried some corrections nothing seemed to work for me, I included this below:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vanleusen.brighthelp">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".HamburgerDrawer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        launchMode ensures intents don't create multiple instances of it
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Map"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>


        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'd highly appreciate it if someone could help me work out why my map's onCreate and onMapReady functions are not being executed.

Comment: Have you checked that "mapFragment" object actually created or not?

Comment: I know its not for sure as the entire MainActivity class is never actually ran, how do I make it run?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14810275/3425390) for starting new activity.

Comment: I had tried that previously however if I do that it opens the map in a new window rather than changing the map fragment in content_hamburger_drawer.xml > FrameLayout >Fragment (with id map) as I wanted it to. Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling MainActivity class from anywhere that's why this problem is coming.Please call it from HamburgerDrawer class in onCreate method or any clicklistener.

```
Intent a=new Intent(getApplicationContext,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(a);
```

Comment: I had tried that previously however if I do that it opens the map in a new window rather than changing the map fragment in content_hamburger_drawer.xml > FrameLayout >Fragment (with id map) as I wanted it to. Any ideas?

Comment: Please go through to this tutorial it will definately help you.

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-google-maps-tutorial-google-maps-android-api/