# Radio button link with button? [Android Studio]

Tags: android, android-studio

Good day, May I know how to link main page to another activity page through radio button with button?

Comment: perhaps this will point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click

Comment: yeah it is simple one as you are using button

Comment: @ZhaoLin Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate it. I initial planing is to make an option for the user to choose enter admin or employee activity page through radio button

Comment: @StuartSiegler thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 final RadioButton admin = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
 final RadioButton employee = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
 final Button go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if (admin.isChecked())
          {
            Intent Intents= new Intent(YourActivity.this, Admin.class); 
            startActivity(Intents);
           }
            else if (employee.isChecked())
           {
             Intent Intentm = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Employee.class); 
             startActivity(Intents);
            }
          }
         });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help @John Joe . I try first