# Interactive android apps

Tags: android

I am new to Android App Development. I am trying to build an interactive app where there are two screens. On the first screen there will be a button. When the button is touched, then another screen will appear. I have already made the first screen. But how do I link the second screen to the first screen? Please help.

Comment: This is literally what the official "getting started" discusses. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: And please use the search  -- [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: Thanks a lot cricket_007!! That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make the second screen a new Activity, and in the buttons onClick method put this to switch to the second activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewScreenActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done by simply using Intent Object

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Please learn what are Intent. There are many tutorial online