# how to start an activity using a button inside an fragment?

Tags: android-studio

Below is the fragment from where i want to start a new activity

```java
public class Admin extends Fragment {
    public Admin() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sathish! What is the probelem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: sir im trying to add a button on a fragment.  if i click that button it shold open new activity but im unable to do dat can u plz help me sir plz./????

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your activity starting process within the `OnClick` function of your button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            FirstActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
}
```

Don't forget to add your second activity in your manifest too

```
<activity android:label="@string/second_activity" android:name="SecondActivity"/>
```

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: how to do that plz can u be specific ?