# How to start an activity when an item from the listview is clicked?

Tags: javascript, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have list items or an array of items in `strings.xml`.
I want to start an `Activity` when an item is clicked but my array list is defined in `strings.xml`. Please Help.
Let's say item number One Opens `ActivityItem1` and so on...

This is my XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:id="@+id/txtsearch"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And This My Strings.xml

```
<resources>

<array name="allduas">
        <item>Item Number 1</item>
        <item>Item Number 2</item>
        <item>Item Number 3</item>
        <item>Item Number 4</item>
        <item>Item Number 5</item>
        <item>Item Number 6</item>
        <item>Item Number 7</item>
        <item>Item Number 8</item>
        <item>Item Number 9</item>
        <item>Item Number 10</item>
        <item>Item Number 10</item>
        <item>Item Number 12</item>
        <item>Item Number 13</item>
        <item>Item Number 14</item>
        <item>Item Number 15</item>
        <item>Item Number 16</item>
        <item>Item Number 17</item>
        <item>Item Number 18</item>
        <item>Item Number 19</item>
        <item>Item Number 20</item>
        <item>Item Number 21</item>
        <item>Item Number 22</item>
        <item>Item Number 23</item>
        <item>Item Number 24</item>
        <item>Item Number 25</item>
        <item>Item Number 26</item>
        <item>Item Number 27</item>
        <item>Item Number 28</item>
        <item>Item Number 29</item>
        <item>Item Number 30</item>

    </array>

</resources>
```

And this is my java file

```
public class AllDuasActivity extends Activity {

    public ListView listView;
    public String[] items;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public AutoCompleteTextView ac;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.allduas);

        ac = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.allduas);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ac.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
        { 
            if(position==1)
            startActivity(this,Activity1.class);
        }
    });
```

try this .

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to do with a `ListView` component. Just add `OnItemClickListener` as following:

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActviity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        });
```

Comment: i want item 1 to start activity1 and item 2 to start activity2,item 3 to start activity3 and so on.....

Comment: Most cases where ListView is involved doesn't require to launch a separate Activity for each list item because this approach smells. Can you share your use case in details?

Answer (score 0):

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
```

Get String className from your xml file for example, but it should be full link such as com.myapp.MyClass. 
Then start Activity with this class name.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemClickListener() {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = null;
            switch (position) {
                case POSITION_ONE:
                    intent = new Intent(context, ActivityOne.class);
                    break;
                case POSITION_TWO:
                    intent = new Intent(context, ActivityTwo.class);
                    break;
                case POSITION_THREE:
                    intent = new Intent(context, ActivityThree.class);
                    break;
            }
            context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You can have as many switch cases as you have activities.