# Get string extra from activity Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get a string extra in another activity from an intent. This is the way to create my intent

```
val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("samplename", "abd")
startActivity(intent)
```

How can i get the value of this intent in the another activity

Comment: you can get it in another activity from `Intent`, e.g: `activity.intent.getExtraString("samplename")`

Comment: In another activity? Is it `Main2Activity` or any activity?

Comment: the intent goes to Main2Activity

Comment: Do you want to get `samplename` from `Main2Activity` or some other class?

Comment: this intent is in the MainActivity, what I want to do, is create the intent, and get the string extra in Main2Activity

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Answer found, in the next activity, you have to do this to get the string:

```
val ss:String = intent.getStringExtra("samplename").toString()
```

Comment: what is "valor"?

Comment: Edited. Changed the name of StringExtra

Comment: equivalent to `intent.extras.getString("samplename")`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. samplename it's a name that i'm using to identify this intent, and catch the value in the next activity. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: How can you call the intent from previous value if you didn't declare it?

Comment: It's declared. In this part of code I just show how to retrieve the value of the intent.

Answer (score 29):

**LOAD**

```
val value: String = txt_act_main.text.toString() // or just your string
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("value", value)
startActivity(intent)
```

//option 2 all inner classes should be implemented to Serializable

```
   getIntent().putExtra("complexObject", clickedTitle);
```

**GET**

```
var bundle :Bundle ?=intent.extras
var message = bundle!!.getString("value") // 1
var strUser: String = intent.getStringExtra("value") // 2
Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

//option 2

```
 var myProg = intent.getSerializableExtra("complexObject") as MenuModel
```

**IMPLICIT (To Share with other apps)**

```
val value: String = txt_act_main.text.toString()
var intent = Intent()
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, value)
intent.type="text/plain"
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share to "))
```

Answer (score 7):

Can use this code :

```
val bundle = intent.extras
var sampleName: String = ""
if (bundle != null) {
    sampleName = bundle.getString("samplename")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can check if the intent value is null or not

```
val bundle :Bundle ?=intent.extras
    if (bundle!=null){
        val message = bundle.getString("object") // 1

        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In Main2Activity you can have your code like this :

```
    val intent = getIntent();
    val myValue = intent.getStringExtra("key")
    Log.d(TAG,"myValue"+myValue)
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer doesn't solve the case where the intent is not there. Because when the key is not exist in intent, `getStringExtra()` will give you `null` even its signature indicates a `String` rather than a `String?`.

You can use `val text:String = intent.getStringExtra(intentKey) ?: ""` to make sure no NPE happened.

But one more answer here:

This is for the case where, you try to retrieve the string from intent, if the value is there, we get the value, otherwise, it will go back to the previous screen because this intent is critical. Something wrong will happen but we don't want to crash the activity.

```
private fun getStringFromIntentOrShowError(intentKey: String):String {
    val text:String? = intent.getStringExtra(intentKey)

    if (text == null) {
        showDialog(
            "Error", 
            "No $intentKey found"
        ) {
            it.dismiss()
            finish()
        }
        return ""
    }

    return text
}

// I use anko to show a dialog, you can use your one.
private fun showDialog(
    title:String,
    message:String,
    yesButtonCallback: (d:DialogInterface) -> Unit
) {
    alert(message, title){ yesButton{
            yesButtonCallback(it)
    } }.show()
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
val text:String = getStringFromIntentOrShowError("asd")
```

and text will always have a value

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple Kotlin Extension

```
fun Intent.getData(key: String): String {
    return extras?.getString(key) ?: "intent is null"
}
```

this Extension checks if the intent value is null, if the value is null it will return **intent is null** otherwise, it will return the value

use it like this

```
val username = intent.getData("username")
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to initialize the intent variable.
Then take out the data like we do in java :)

```
val intent: Intent = intent
var data = intent.getStringExtra("mydata")
```