# Implementation of onItemClickListener in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

How to implement an `onItemClickListener()` on a custom `listView` in kotlin?_

```
title_list_view.setOnItemClickListener{ adapterView: AdapterView<*>?, 
    view: View?, position: Int, l: Long ->
}
```

what to do to start a new activity after clicking an item of a Custom `ListView`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: no..it isnt the same thing....

Comment: Well, to start an `Activity` you should do like that, regardless of the source (a `Button`, a `ListView` or anything else). Then if you get exceptions/other issues it's another story (and you should provide more info on the issue you get)

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
    title_list_view.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->   

      Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked item :"+" "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        this.startActivity(intent);
     }
```

Comment: tried this..but activities not starting.....but toast is wrking....that's all...my program Shuts down..whenEver i try starting activity like this,..

Comment: What exception do you get when you app shuts off?

Answer (score 1):

You are using kotlin right?

use **NextActivity::class.java** in Intent

```
title_list_view.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->   

  Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked item : $position",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("position", position)
    this.startActivity(intent)
 }
```