# How can I build an mobile App that has two different kinds of startup behaviour?

Tags: android, ios, game-engine, startup

I want to build a mobile app that combines a task managing app with an RPG PvE experience.
Now to my Problem i would like to give the User the Option to load the App on two different modes.

1. Productive Mode
   In this mode only the task managing features will be loaded. This mode would be behaviour like a standard business app.
2. Gaming Mode
   When starting the app in gaming mode you will be able to manage your task and get the gaming experience. This mode would be behaviour like a normal Gaming App.

Now to my Questions. 
How could i achieve this? 
Is this even Possible at the moment and what would I need to create something like that? 
To create the gaming part i would like to use the Godot Engine or Unity3D is it possible with these engines to make these thinks?

Answer (score 2):

You would just need to show a splash screen of some sort, with a simple selection of what the user would want to do.

```
Button btnBusiness = findViewById(R.id.businessButton);
btnBusiness.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent businessIntent = new Intent(this, BusinessActivity.class);
        startActivity(businessIntent);
    }
});

Button btnGaming = findViewById(R.id.gamingButton);
btnGaming.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Gamer headset: On
        //Knuckles cracked
        //Intent created
        //Yep.. its gamer time
        Intent businessIntent = new Intent(this, GamingActivity.class);
        startActivity(businessIntent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes It's possible

But if you don't know the basics of Android App development.
Start with [What is an Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity)

And once you know the basics.
You can create Three Activities to deal with your requirements .

1. `WelcomeActivity`
2. `GamingActivity`
3. `ProductiveActivity`

Give some selection for a user in the `WelcomeActivity`.
You can add two Buttons for each Mode (Activity).
When the user clicks on the game option, it opens `GameActivity` and so on.
Now if you don't know how to move from one activity to another activity, you should read these.

[What is an intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)
[How to start an Activity on Button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click/44166727#44166727)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, however you will have to set the default startup and choose next startup according to user preference.

Both [Ezzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2664634/ezzy) and [Rohit Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4700156/rohit-singh) answers can lead to what you need but if your app is going to be very heavy and/or many functionalities at once in the app and/or for any other performance reason, I think it's better to separate the two apps and make one for the game and another one for the standard business app.

Like Uber and Uber for drivers...