# How can I load an activity when user connection error?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 2 activities **MainActivity** and **ErrorActivity**.

When the user has no connection, I want to redirect him from **MainActivity** to **ErrorActivity**.

This is my *MainActivity* File:

```
package com.xcoder.onestep;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);



    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onRecievedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String   description, String faillingUrl) {


        }

    });



}

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

I want to use it without button, when no connection redirect user to the *ErrorActivity.class*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean haveNetworkConnection(Context context) {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

Use Above Function and put a check in  oncreate

```
if(!haveNetworkConnection(this)){

 startActivity(new Intent(this,ErrorActivity.Class));
}
```