# Open Activity by clicking in the menu button- Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

**I am a beginner**, **I am a few days with this problem**

I didn't find a solution. I have a menu that appears in an activity and when I click, I want it to open a new activity.

My question is, what to put in the activity with menu, and what to put in the new activity?

This is my code

---

**Menu_chat.xml   (my menu)**

```
   android:id="@+id/salva_vida"
   android:icon="@drawable/salva_vida"
   android:title="@string/save_life"
   app:showAsAction="always" />
```

---

**ChatActivity.java  (this is the activity with menu)**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            case R.id.salva_vida:
                ???????  (What put here?)------------------
                break;
```

---

**tab2.java   (this is the new activity- I want to open this)**

```
public class tab2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, tab2.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Your ChatActivity.java will look like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

        case R.id.salva_vida:
            //Start Activity here
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, tab2.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, tab2.class); startActivity(mIntent);

@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { int id = item.getItemId(); switch (id) { case android.R.id.home: onBackPressed(); return true; case R.id.salva_vida: //Start Activity here Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, tab2.class); startActivity(mIntent); break;

Don't forget to add your tab2 activity to manifest.