# How do you make a button in android that opens a new activity and this activity is not just a default activity its a custom one

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying a make notepad app so every time a new note is opened the layout will be the same. also, the number of activity(new note) should not be defined as many possible

Comment: you can call your own activity again by `new Intent(this, YourActivity.class)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4186097/5705721

Comment: If your app is similar to notepad then why you need multiple activity. You can use recyclerview and change data accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

If the activity is always the same, you should probably create an adapter that allows you to change the texts and images of your activity without the need to create several activities.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out