# How can I change my android activity on button click? - Stack Overflow

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am new to programming and don't know how to jump from one activity to another activity.

The first Activity name is Splash and the Second one name is Home.

**I am trying to jump from Splash to Home.**

Can Anybody help me to do so?

Comment: Look into a Navigation tutorial, and consider using (if it applies to you) Fragments instead of Activities for your application screens/parts with just a single Activity.
See: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your button in splash activity and you want to redirect main activity on button click you can write code like below.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.class,HomeActivity.class); but it shows an error

Comment: Thanks now its work i change SplashActivity.class to SplashActivity.this

Comment: sorry check my answer again

Comment: Thanks @Bhavik Kalsariya  now its work I change SplashActivity.class to SplashActivity.this

Comment: ok if you think this answer is useful then accept answer. Thanks

Comment: bro, I am casting a vote but it shows me that you need at least 15 reputations.

Comment: ok np, thanks again