# setOnClickListener start another activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to start another activity by pressing on the cardview which has a friend finder id. But when I write home.java it gives me problems in the setOnClickListener. At homeActivity it tells me Cannot resolve method 'homeActivity' in 'HomeActivity'. because?

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CardView btn_home;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_home = findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.home);

    btn_home.setOnClickListener(v -> homeActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, TrovamicoActivity.class)));

}
```

Comment: logs? more code? What is that homeActivity anyway, how is it declared, where does it reside?

Comment: HomeActivity is this the code, what should I put instead of homeActivity?

Comment: [Looking for this probably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4186097/681929)

Comment: I am using a cardview, is that okay too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btn_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, TrovamicoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }

    });
```

If there is no code in the manifest, write it

```
<activity android:name=".TrovamicoActivity" />
```

Comment: what is orderButton? i'm using cardview in my home.xml

Comment: can you check it again i edited my code

Comment: In TrovamicoActivity  I have a problem with ActivityMapsBinding for google maps I asked another question can you check? because I can't see if it works for me if the other activity doesn't work for me. Thx

Comment: I can take a look at the other problem, if I send a link

Comment: the code is working, I tried it, you can confirm if you want

Comment: If you approve, it will be useful both for me and for other users. Just click the checkmark to confirm.